# How to open port in Android?

Tags: android, sockets, connection, port

How can I open a specific port in android?

I have a server socket but the connection is rejected because the port is closed.

```
try {
   ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(2021);
   Socket client = server.accept(); 
} catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   a = false;
   e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

Comment: tell us what you tried so far and show us some code. Also - repeating the same question is considered bad here.

Comment: Maybe application have to have INTERNET permission. Check it.

Answer (score 1):

If you still havn't got it to work, I would suggest that you create an inner class that extends Thread to replace that whole `new Thread() {`...`}.start()` statement (I have always had trouble getting those to work exactly right when I try to declare an instance field, I just stick with creating/overriding methods in that kind of statement).  I would make the inner class, say `ClientAnsweringThread`, have a constructor that takes in the Socket (`client`) as a parameter and then calls `ProcessClientRequest(_client);` in the `run()` method as you already have.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you are just missing a loop around the `accept()` call so you can accept multiple connections. Something like this:

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket( port );

while ( true )
{
    Socket client = server.accept();
    ProcessClientRequest( client );
}
```

Comment: And accept it into a separate thread so it can perform its work asynchronously rather than one at a time.

Comment: Sigh ... it doesn't have to be threads. Only pay for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate what I meant in my comment:

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket( port );
while ( true )
{
    Socket client = server.accept();
    new Thread () { 
        final Socket _client = client;
        // This stuff runs in a separate thread all by itself
        public void run () {
            ProcessClientRequest(_client);
        }
    }.start();
}
```